# Line by line not working

Tags: bash

**Script**

```
FILE="/u0146121/bin/list.txt"
while read line; do 
echo $line 
done < $FILE
```

I am new to bash scripting and trying to figure out this while loop. I want to read line by line from a text file and then do a command.

**I keep getting the error:**

```
 No such file or directory121/bin/list.txt
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried adding a second `echo` after the first? `echo $line; echo`. It won't solve your problem, but it might allow you to see the full error message. I don't see anything obviously wrong with your script, other than possibly the file name.

Comment: What happens if you replace the shebang line with `#!/bin/bash -x` ? (`-x` and `-v` enable extra debugging information).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect your script may have DOS-style line endings. In DOS (and Windows), each line of a text file ends with carriage return (variously represented as `\r` or `^M`) followed by a linefeed (`\n` or `^J`). Unix text files, on the other hand, end each line with just a linefeed. If you give a unix tool (like bash) a DOS-formatted file, it'll interpret the carriage return as part of the line, and get quite confused. In this case, it looks to me like FILE is actually getting set to `/u0146121/bin/list.txt^M`, which doesn't exist, and when the shell reports the problem the carriage return confuses the terminal and the end of the error message gets printed over top of the beginning.

To check, try printing your script with `cat -v /path/to/script` -- if you see ^M at the end of lines, you have a DOS-format file. Your system probably has a command to translate it, but the command name varies (e.g. it might be `dos2unix` or `fromdos` or ...). If you can't find a relevant command, you can use this trivial perl script:

```
perl -pi -e 's/\r//g' /path/to/script
```

Comment: you are right it does have a ^M.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not showing us exactly what you are doing. The error message is

```
No such file or directory121/bin/list.txt
```

which shows that `$FILE` contains `121/bin/list.txt` instead of `/u0146121/bin/list.txt` so I can only guess that you are not actually running `FILE="/u0146121/bin/list.txt"` but `FILE="121/bin/list.txt"`.

In any case, try running it without defining a variable to see if it works:

```
while read line; do 
  echo $line;
done < /u0146121/bin/list.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
FILE="/u0146121/bin/list.txt"
while read line; do 
echo $line 
done < cat $FILE
```

Comment: This isn't any different, except it's a [Useless Use of cat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUOC#Useless_use_of_cat).